# Entity Framework Can Not Save My Change

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, automapper, dto

I'm using the following design:

[image: System architecture]

I'm using AutoMapper for the domain/DTO conversions (both ways), Entity Framework Code First, and SQL Server 2012.

Each table has a field named `RowVersion` of type `timestamp` in order to check updates.

I'm using a DTO layer because my domain objects can't be serialized in WCF services, and I have a cycle in my domain layer.

Anyway, my problem is that when create a `Bank` (one table with a single page in the UI) I copy the values (BankCode, BankName) into `BankDTO` and in my service layer I convert `BankDTO` to `BankDomain` (the entity domain object for `Bank`) using AutoMapper, then call `SaveChange`.

That works, and I can update the bank too.

But when I edit one `Bank` and a bank branch, then convert `BankDTO` TO `BankDomain` and call `SaveChange`, that doesn't work. If I map `BankDTO` to `BankDomain` *without* AutoMapper, that works and the update is performed.

My `BankDTO` looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class BankModel
{

    public BankModel()
    {
        this.BankBranches = new List<BankBranchModel>();
    }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; } 
    public decimal BankCode { get; set; } 
    public string BankName { get; set; } 
    public string LatinCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BankBranchModel> BankBranches { get; set; }

}
```

And the `BankBranch` DTO:

```
[Serializable]
public class BankBranchModel
{

    public BankBranchModel()
    {

    }

    public int BankId { get; set; }
    public decimal BranchCode { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; } 
    public int? ExecutiveUnitId { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; } 
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; } 
    public BankModel Bank { get; set; } 

}
```

`BankDomain`:

```
public class Bank : BaseEntity
{
    public Bank()
    {
        this.BankBranches = new List<BankBranch>();     
    }
    public decimal BankCode { get; set; } 
    public string BankName { get; set; } 
    public string LatinCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BankBranch> BankBranches { get; set; }
}
```

And `BankBranchDomain`:

```
public class BankBranch : BaseEntity
{
    public BankBranch()
    {
    }
    public int BankId { get; set; } 
    public decimal BranchCode { get; set; } 
    public string BranchName { get; set; } 

    public virtual Bank  Bank { get; set; }    
}
```

The SQL table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [global].[Bank](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[BankCode] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[BankName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[LatinCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PKBnk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      
            ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [global].[BankBranch](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[BranchCode] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[BranchName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[BankId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ExecutiveUnitId] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BankBranch] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  
            ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And the update code:

```
using (var db = new AndishmandTestContext())
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<BankModel, Bank>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Bank, BankModel>();

    Mapper.CreateMap<BankBranchModel, BankBranch>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<BankBranch, BankBranchModel>();

    var oldb = db.Banks.Include("BankBranches").Where(b => b.Id == 1);
    Bank bank = oldb.FirstOrDefault();
    BankModel bankmodel = new BankModel();
    Mapper.Map(bank, bankmodel);
}
```

After changing the `BankModel` in the UI layer, this code executes in the service layer:

```
var Newb = db.Banks.Include("BankBranches").Where(b => b.Id == 1);
Bank newbank = Newb.FirstOrDefault();
Mapper.Map(bankmodel, newbank);
```

Then the change is saved in the business layer:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

If I map `BankDto` and `BankBranchDto` in `BankDomain` and `BankBranchDomain` instead of using `Mapper.Map`, then `SaveChanges` works - but I have to use AutoMapper.

Comment: "It not work" isn't nearly enough information about what actually happens. Is there an exception? Does it go through without an exception but just not alter any data in the database? Also note that you don't need to make each sentence into its own paragraph.

Comment: It is _very_ confusing that you use two names for your objects. Please, stick to the class names only. And again, it is not clear what _doesn't work_.

Comment: Jon Skeet : it was done but any data in database change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finded my answer. I changeed my map and it woked

like this

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<BankModel, Bank>().ForMember(x => x.BankBranches, opt => opt.Ignore());
            //Mapper.CreateMap<BankModel, Bank>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Bank, BankModel>();

            Mapper.CreateMap<BankBranchModel, BankBranch>().ForMember(x => x.Bank, opt => opt.Ignore());
            //Mapper.CreateMap<BankBranchModel, BankBranch>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<BankBranch, BankBranchModel>();
```

And then i most modify my domains like this

```
              //update bankdomain
            Mapper.Map(bankmodel, newbank);

            //Update bank branchdomain
            newbank.BankBranches.ToList().ForEach(bb => Mapper.Map(bankmodel.BankBranches.First(c => c.Id == bb.Id), bb));

            //Delete branchdomain
            foreach (var bBmodel in bankmodel.BankBranches.Where(bB => bB.IsDeleted == true))
            {
                newbank.BankBranches.Remove(newbank.BankBranches.Where(bb => bb.Id == bBmodel.Id).First());
            }

            //Add branchdomain
            foreach (var bBM in bankmodel.BankBranches.Where(c => c.Id == null))
            {
                newbank.BankBranches.Add(Mapper.Map<BankBranch>(bBM));
            }
```

and then

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add object or values first which you have changed then save the changes.

```
  db.Banks.AddObject(---your object name or value which you want to add---);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: in service Layer i query old bank and i add object and values chaned into this domain with this code : var Newb = db.Banks.Include("BankBranches").Where(b => b.Id == 1);
            Bank newbank = Newb.FirstOrDefault();
            Mapper.Map(bankmodel, newbank);

Comment: Mapper.Map(bankmodel, newbank); it must be modified all changes

Comment: Reason Mapper.Map(bankmodel, newbank) may not store as a same EF object  for current object values